# regular expression for name with some symbols

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I was scratching my head for regular expression to validate name field
which will accept
Only characters
Space
Dash
apostrophe
and dot

I tried

```
/^[0-9A-Za-z_@'-]+$/
```

but this is going wrong

Comment: Person name field or user name field? Are you sure you need the regex delimiters  (`/.../`)?

Comment: Why `@` character ? BTW you haven't included `.` character in class. Use it like this in class after escaping. `\.`

Comment: try this ([\w\s\-\.\']+)

Comment: check here https://regex101.com/r/iA6kQ8/2

Answer (score 0):

Try this expresion

```
/^[0-9A-Za-z .@'-]+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to escape the '-' char because it has another meaning in regexes.
The following should take care of what you need

```
^[A-z.'\-@_ ]+$
```

Comment: @Fattycoder: you can do that by removing the '0-9' part, as shown in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression

```
^[a-zA-Z\s-'.]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this below code allows what you expecting.

`([A-Z .'-])\w+`

Output Sample:

```
Edit the Expression
gskinner.com
OMG-B
```

Let try above code and let us know.